# PHP Imagick - Text and Lines not clear/smooth after resize

Tags: php, resize, crop, imagick

Using PHP's Imagick library I am taking an image, resizing, cropping and setting an overlay over the top. This works fine but for images that have text or thin/intricate lines the results are very jagged.

I set the quality to 90 on output so that shouldn't be the issue. Is there anything I am doing wrong during resize/crop etc?

Link can be seen below:

http://www.tiltworld.co.uk/resize.php

http://www.tiltworld.co.uk/output.jpg

As you can see the outputted image quality is very poor with the text and lines, jagged or hard to see/read.

Here is the original full size before resizing:

http://www.tiltworld.co.uk/test.jpg

My PHP code is:

step 1: set the images

```
$overlay = new Imagick('http://www.tiltworld.co.uk/overlay.png');
$img = new Imagick('http://www.tiltworld.co.uk/test.jpg');
$img_d = $img->getImageGeometry(); 
$img_w = $img_d['width']; 
$img_h = $img_d['height'];
```

step 2: resize the image

```
// resize
$crop_w = round(260 * 0.53);
$crop_h = round(260 * 0.53);
list($_w, $_h) = scaleProportions($crop_w, $crop_h, $img_w, $img_h);
$img->adaptiveResizeImage($_w, $_h);
```

step 3: crop the image

```
// crop
$new_d = $img->getImageGeometry(); 
$new_w = $new_d['width']; 
$new_h = $new_d['height'];
$crop_x = ($new_w - $crop_w) / 2;
$crop_y = ($new_h - $crop_h) / 2;
$img->cropImage($crop_w, $crop_h, $crop_x, $crop_y);
```

step 4: place the image in center

```
// place
$img->setImageFormat('png');
$img->setImageBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('white'));
$place_x = -(260 - $crop_w) / 2; 
$place_y = -(260 - $crop_h) / 2;
$img->extentImage(260, 260, $place_x, $place_y);
```

step 5: merge image and overlay

```
// merge
$img->compositeImage($overlay, imagick::COMPOSITE_ATOP, 0, 0);
```

step 6: output the image

```
// output
header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
$img->setImageFormat('jpg');
$img->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$img->setImageCompressionQuality(90);
echo $img->getImageBlob();
```

(scale function used on resize)

```
function scaleProportions($mw, $mh, $cw, $ch)
{
    $scale = $mh / $ch; 
    $ch = $mh; 
    $cw = $cw * $scale;
    if($cw>=$mw){
        if($ch>=$mh)
        {
            return array($cw, $ch);
        }
        else 
        {
            $scale = $mw / $cw; 
            $cw = $mw; 
            $ch = $ch * $scale;
            return array($cw, $ch);
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        $scale = $mw / $cw; 
        $cw = $mw; 
        $ch = $ch * $scale;
        return array($cw, $ch);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a weird resize method. Try using the one that allows you to control how the filtering is done:

$imagick->resizeImage($width, $height, \Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1, false);